# delayed_job tasks failing in daemon mode in production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job

I'm trying to use delayed_jobs. It works perfectly, locally, when using the rake jobs:work task. However, when I try to use it as a daemon, the tasks fail. I've stopped it from deleting failed tasks. I'm starting the daemon with '**RAILS_ENV=production bin/delayed_jobs start**'. When I do **status** it shows the worker is active.

They seem to be failing with this error **'Job failed to load: undefined class/module ProductAquisition.'**

This is a snippet from the module I'm trying to use (lib/product_aquisition.rb).

```
module ProductAquisition

    require 'net/http'

    def ProductAquisition.get_updates
         .....
    end

end
```

This is from the rakefile I'm trying to use to trigger this

```
require 'debugger'
require 'date'
require 'thread'
# require 'active_support'

require "#{Rails.root}/lib/product_aquisition.rb"
require "#{Rails.root}/app/helpers/soap_helper"
include SoapHelper
include ProductAquisition



task :get_updates => :environment do

    ProductAquisition.delay.get_updates

end
```

I don't understand how it's unable to load and use the module 'ProductAquisition' when running as a daemon. Can anyone shed some light on this?

**Edit: Full error message**

Full error output can be seen here: https://gist.github.com/smithmr8/70f1f736fe1c679ceff1/raw/9586759c868adce3797ad9e7697789ef417821a6/gistfile1.rb

I tried posting it here but it wouldn't wrap correctly.

Comment: Why the file is names `ProductAquisition.rb`? It's against convention so autoloader doesn't pick it up!

Comment: This will not work as well unless it's Windoze machine `require "#{Rails.root}/lib/productaquisition.rb"` because POSIX systems are case-sensitive. Rename file to `product_aquisition.rb` and all will be dandy (and do not require it by hand, autoloader should do that for you)

Comment: I changed the name of the file to the one suggested, removed the manual require / includes, but it just results in an 'Undefined constant' error.

Comment: It works fine if I start delayed_jobs with rake jobs:work and then run rake get_updates. However, if I start it as a daemon via RAILS_ENV=production bin/delayed_job start and then run rake get_updates it produces the error. I can't find anything to explain why this is happening or how I'd go about solving it.

Comment: Ok, maybe `bin/delayed_job` doesn't use autoloading, so - keep the changed file name but add `require '#{Rails.root}/lib/product_aquisitions.rb` as well. And remember that Linux systems are case-sensitive so you shouldn't name files in this matter. For safety always use lowercase.

Comment: The file was originally lowercase. The only difference now is the addition of the underscore. It still behaves the same way.

Comment: Looking at the code below, where the require is actually used. And, I quote: 'require "#{Rails.root}/lib/productaquisition.rb"'.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I am unable to help if you give such tangled information. Update a post and mind the case-sensitivity of file names, etc., add whole error log, maybe someone will be able to help.

Comment: I've already included everything in my post that is of relevance to the problem. It's pretty clear cut. It doesn't work when it's running as a daemon. The error that is returned is included in the original post.